# Integrating over a symmetry vector field by exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry, symmetry, lie-algebra

Take some constant-of-motion, $H$, and the Poisson bracket, $\{\cdot, \cdot\}$. Then, we recover the symmetry vector field of $H$ by

\begin{equation}
S_H = \{\cdot, H\}
\end{equation}

so take for example a circle, $H = x^2 + y^2$, then our symmetry vector field becomes

\begin{equation}
S_H = 2y\partial_x - 2x\partial_y
\end{equation}

where inputs of a point on this circle will output tangential pointing vectors on the circle. If I had a particle on this circle, I can theoretically march it forward along this field. Now, take the $SO(2)$ generator

\begin{equation}
X_g = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

which then, using the exponential map, I can march the particle along the same vector field by

\begin{equation}
x_0 \exp(2tX_g) = x_f
\end{equation}

I had to handwave and add the $2$ to get the scaling to match that from $S_H$. How would I get an expression similar to above, except instead of using $X_g$, it uses $S_H$? Using

\begin{equation}
x_0 \exp(tS_H)
\end{equation}

doesn't seem right since $S_H$ is a 1-d vector field and the exponential map doesn't make sense to me in this context. I *could* look at the structure of the constant-of-motion and symmetry and realize they are described by $SO(2)$, however I'm looking for something a little more automated.

Comment: You can take the exponential of a vector field (google it!), and it is basically exactly what you’re looking for.

Comment: Right I've googled this quite a bit and I know you _can_ do it, something is lost on me on the _how_ you do it though. I should also mention that I do not have a background in Lie theory or math. This is all self taught so it's very likely I've missed a simple concept.